# Changing Buffered Image for and object

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm trying to create a game from scratch, and my question is directed towards the background image for that said game. This project is probably a precursor for me creating games on a greater scale. In this situation, I'm wanting to change the image it loads for the background depending on what room the game says its in. right now I have two room images, but I can't seem to get it to change the image after it has first been brought up. I don't want to load too big of a file and then use it like a sprite sheet, mainly because I don't want to have framerate issues in the future when the rooms get larger and there is a lot to load as well as the background. My question is, how do I change the image that the background will load in?

I have found several people with the same problem, and there may be answers to this question out there, but I am new-ish to programming so some of the language that is used might be foreign to me.

```
package com.game.main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Texture {

    SpriteSheet es, ps, ws, bg;
    private BufferedImage enemy_sheet = null;
    private BufferedImage player_sheet = null;
    private BufferedImage weapon_sheet = null;
    private BufferedImage background = null;

    public BufferedImage[] enemy = new BufferedImage[2];
    public BufferedImage[] player = new BufferedImage[9];
    public BufferedImage[] weapon = new BufferedImage[9];
    public String[] roomim = new String[9];
    public BufferedImage room;

    public Texture()
        {
        BuffImLoad loader = new BuffImLoad();
        try{
            enemy_sheet = loader.loadImage("/SpriteSheetEn1.png");
            player_sheet = loader.loadImage("/SpriteSheet.png");
            weapon_sheet = loader.loadImage("/SSWeapon.png");

            int roomnum = Values.getRoomnum();
            background = loader.loadImage(roomloader(roomnum));

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        es = new SpriteSheet(enemy_sheet);
        ps = new SpriteSheet(player_sheet);
        ws = new SpriteSheet(weapon_sheet);
        bg = new SpriteSheet(background);

        getTextures();
        getRoom();
        }

    private void getTextures(){
        enemy[0] = es.grabImage(1,1,56, 53);//idol en1


        player[0] = ps.grabImage(1, 1, 34, 50);//temp player image

        weapon[0] = ws.grabImage(1, 1, 7, 47);//temp player image


    }
    private void getRoom(){
        room = bg.grabBG(0, 0, 3840 ,2160);
    }
    private String roomloader(int x){
        roomim[0] = ("/Bgtemp.png");
        roomim[1] = ("/Bgtemp2.png");
        //roomim[1] = 
        return roomim[x];
    }

}
```